# What is the logic behind peak interest rates for 390 days FDs in India?

Tags: india, interest

Currently fixed deposit (FD) rates in India are around 9% p.a with various Indian banks. I have observed that there are tenure brackets which start from 7 days till 5 years. There is always a bracket where interest rates peak which is 390 days. What is logic of having peak interest rates at 390 days? Why not any other tenure?

Comment: I didn't realize yields in India were so high!  Typically this would relate to the bond yield curve which relates to the future expectations about rates.

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7084/interest-rates-on-fixed-deposits-in-india-why-would-rates-for-1-year-deposits-b?rq=1

Comment: But why 390 days.. Is there something specific about this number? Is there any specific event linked to this?

Comment: @GuySirton [inflation in India](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/india/inflation-cpi) is also very high compared to current levels in western countries.  It's really not any better of a deal than you'd get for a short term CD where you live.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to figure this mystery around 390 days for sometime and finally came across this article on [mystery of odd FD tenures](http://articles.economictimes.indiatimes.com/2010-12-28/news/27632192_1_fds-deposits-tenures/)

It seems that this is linked to loan cycle for the banks -

> These time periods are meant to match the bank's asset and liability in a particular bucket. Say, it has higher demand for one-year loans, then it will offer a 390-day deposit. Similarly, the 700-day deposits are meant to match the asset and liability for two-year loans.
>
> Simply put, banks are ensuring they have money to give loans by extending the tenure of matching FDs. As the FDs mature a little later, it gives them more breathing space to get the money back from the borrowers and return it to the depositors.